# How to make a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, causality, singularities

Many Physics discussions I have often conclude with:

> Well you will then form a black hole...

My questions are:

- Is there a general recipe for making a black hole?
- If not, then can you list the families of black hole causes?

This means I can put a more rapid halt to many future Physics discussions.

Comment: A general recipe for creating a black hole requires a general solution of the Einstein Field equations - but this has not yet been created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever an amount of mass (or mass equivalent in energy) finds itself inside a volume smaller than the event-horizon for a Schwarzschild black hole of that mass ($R = \frac{Gm}{c^2}$), then you have the necessary and sufficient condition for a black hole. In fact, the black hole may form *before* the matter reaches this point, provided that it *will* reach it some time in the future.

What kind of discussions are you having?

Comment: Cheers for this @lionelbrits,

Comment: It seems rather straightforward then, not sure why it hasn't been brought up. Here are some discussions leading to that: "how many photons can you fit into a unit of space", "what happens if superman punched you?", "what happens if you create a very loud noise? (more specifically the "fus do rah" in skyrim), and a lot of things involving high energy, time travel, curving space time.

Comment: This is the hoop conjecture. Which, as far as I know, is still an open problem.

Comment: I think what I meant would be a stronger requirement (a sphere)

Answer (score 1):

A black hole can be formed if the gravitational force at any point $r$ of the physical object with mass $m$ is greater than a constant force as written below[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/368922267_On_the_origin_of_gravity_and_the_emergence_of_a_black_hole?channel=doi&linkId=6400aad9b1704f343f980c47&showFulltext=true),

$$\frac {c^4}{G} \leq \frac {Gm^2}{r^2}$$

if this is the condition under which an object will attain the Schwarzschild radius and become a black hole-like object.

[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/368922267_On_the_origin_of_gravity_and_the_emergence_of_a_black_hole?channel=doi&linkId=6400aad9b1704f343f980c47&showFulltext=true) Kapil chandra, On the origin of gravity and the emergence of a black hole, DOI: [10.13140/RG.2.2.25367.24485](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/368922267_On_the_origin_of_gravity_and_the_emergence_of_a_black_hole?channel=doi&linkId=6400aad9b1704f343f980c47&showFulltext=true).